# difference between npm run and nmp start?

Tags: javascript, npm

we have a lot of ts code which we can compile and run via "npm run dev".  This allows us to hit the test js code via localhost.  however, in the chrome debugger, 90% of the code is not visible (anonymous), and code which is not is too generic (such as find) to figure out how the thing which the debugger is showing as being slow or called a lot relates to our source code.

Comment: What’s the question here?

Comment: You can figure out what the scripts do by looking at the scripts entry in `package.json`.

Comment: I think you need to set up your build tools to generate source maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm run Will execute one of the npm definitions in package.json

npm start is a script defined on package.json (same as npm run sart, its a shortcut)